# Replacing a particular string in a unix script with sed

Tags: shell, unix, replace, sed, solaris

I have a string like below

```
/home/adcde
```

to be replaced with `efgh`

so the same `adcde` is used some where else in the script which I don't want to replace.

so If I am replacing with the below command

`sed 's/adcde/efgh/g'` - it replaces the all of it

so instead I want to replace the `adcde` that starts with a `/`

```
 sed 's/"/adcde"/efgh/g'
```

but it does not seem to work

any help would be appreciate?

Answer (score 0):

sed 's:/adcde:/efgh:g'- solved the issue

Thanks to Benjamin for pointing it out